# Identify this automotive flat-pinned connector

Tags: connector

This connector is from the wiper controller on an old Jeep Cherokee.  (The relay seems to have destroyed the board.)  Most of each blade is housed in plastic and the tips plug into matching female pins.  Each pin seems to be individually soldered onto the PCB.

[image: Mystery connector]

In the housing, they look like this.

[image]

Here's what the females look like.

[image]

What is this type of pin/connector called?  I would like to buy replacements.

Comment: It's called "Custom".

Comment: Ha! So little chance of finding something suitable?

Comment: @thirtythreeforty  You might have some luck with recovering the terminals (pins) from your own deceased boards, or from junkyard.

Comment: That's what I was going to punt to.  I was merely wondering if this is a standard design or if it is totally custom.

Comment: They'll be custom made sprung brass contacts. Reclamation is really your only option unless you have access to the right kind of press...

Comment: If they are 3/16 or 1/4 wide they may happen to fit Lucas spade grips, but without the locking hole, for an unofficial fix. Not recommended.

Comment: Good idea, although I can't find any spade connectors that can be soldered.  Can you aim me at a part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an obscure connector!  They are Delphi Pack-Con III terminals.  This style of connector is often used to hold blade fuses.  The [State Wire and Terminal catalog](http://statewire.com/pdf/Swat_114_Full_Catalog.pdf) shows several of them:

[image]

The male pins don't really match the picture here, but the female pins definitely match.  It seems that instead of crimping them, this board has soldered them vertically.